# Calling any method on Nothing

Tags: kotlin, subtyping

Although it [is not explicitly stated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) that Nothing is the subtype of all types, this (among others) suggests it:

```
fun f(x:Float) { }
fun g(x:Char) { }

fun dead(q: Nothing) {
    f(q)
    g(q)
}
```

However, this fails with “unresolved reference”:

```
fun dead(q: Nothing) {
    q.not()
}
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Notes:

1. First piece of code compiles (with warnings), second does not
2. It's possible to use a `Nothing` typed receiver, for instance calling `toString()`
3. This is legal: `{b:Boolean -> b.not()}(q)`
4. Upcast too: `(q as Boolean).not()`
5. [Equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042663/when-is-nothing-a-legal-receiver) for Scala

Answer (score 4):

`Nothing` is `Nothing` for a reason. You can't call any functions on it. Besides `not()` is only applicable for `Boolean` so it is not present on `Nothing`. In fact there are no methods on `Nothing`:

```
/**
 * Nothing has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists": for example,
 * if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception).
 */
public class Nothing private constructor()
```

The documentation pretty much explains its existence.

There is one loophole though. What happens if you return `Nothing?` from a function?

```
fun dead(): Nothing? {
    return null
}
```

That's right. It can only return `null`:

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    dead() // will be null
}
```

I wouldn't say that there is a valid use case to do this but it is possible.

An example for `Nothing` to indicate nothingness in trees:

```
sealed class Tree<out T>() {
    data class Node<out T>(val value: T,
                           val left: Tree<T> = None,
                           val right: Tree<T> = None): Tree<T>()
    object None: Tree<Nothing>()
}
```

Here `Nothing` denotes a leaf node with no children.

Comment: ... and `null` is the only instance of `Nothing?`, which is why it can be assigned to all (nullable) types and which is why in `var a = null`, the inferred type for `a` is `Nothing?`

Comment: Well, actually, you can :-) Try toString().

Comment: You can call [this `toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) on it, because it's an extension on `Any?`.

Comment: There are no instances of `Nothing` because it is nothing. It is only there to indicate nothingness. Like an exception.

Answer (score 3):

The premise itself doesn't make sense. `Nothing` is a class which can not be instantiated. You'll never have a variable that holds a `Nothing` instance.

This means that a function that takes `Nothing` as a parameter can never be invoked, because you can't get a `Nothing` instance to pass to it. Anything you write inside it is irrelevant, as is a function like this existing in the first place.

`Nothing` is made to act like a subtype to all types so that certain uses of language features like `throw` and `return` work nicely with the type system. In essence, the compiler lets you pass a `Nothing` in places where some other type is required, because it knows that you'll never actually reach that code (because again, you can't get a `Nothing` instance), so it doesn't matter what you're passing in.

Comment: The function is dead code, agreed. However, inside some calls generates errors others don't.

Comment: I believe my last paragraph addresses this. You can't call anything on it, because that's nonsense. You can still pass it into any function because it's convenient sometimes and it doesn't break type safety, because that call will never happen.

Comment: Then why not allow using it as receiver for anything ? It is harmless as well :-)

Comment: Yes, but nobody actually needs that in practice, while being able to pass `Nothing` as a parameter is useful, for example it lets you use `throw` and `return` expressions on the right hand side of the Elvis operator without affecting the return type of the expression (which is the first common supertype of the left and right sides of the operator, that being the type on the left if the right one is `Nothing`).