# When is Nothing a legal receiver?

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, subtyping, bottom-type

Being the [subtype of every other type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) allows a hypothetical `Nothing` typed value to be passed to any function. However, although such a value can serve as receiver for `toString()` it can't for `unary_!` (among others).

```
object Foo {
    def dead(q: Nothing): Unit = {
        println(q);
        q.toString();
        ((b: Boolean) => !b)(q);
        !q; // value unary_! is not a member of Nothing
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Note:

1. This is the Scala version of an [equivalent question I asked on Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039255/calling-any-method-on-nothing).
2. Upcasting works: `!(q.asInstanceOf[Boolean])`

Comment: In general, subtyping != inheritance, even though most OOP mainstream languages tend to mix it up, so that the two notions appear almost synonymous.

Comment: Say you could invoke any method that could ever have been defined on a variable of type `Nothing`, what good would it do to allow such programs?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need upcasting. You only have to ascribe some type which has a method `unary_!`:

```
def dead(q: Nothing): Unit = {
  !(q: Boolean)
}
```

Without an explicit type ascription, the method `unary_!` simply cannot be resolved, because even though `Nothing` is a *subtype* of `Boolean`, it's not a *subclass* of `Boolean`, therefore the compiler can not find a method `unary_!` in the inheritance hierarchy of `Nothing`.

The fact that you can define such methods and functions is not a bug either. The following is a completely valid program that uses a function with input type `Nothing` to produce a perfectly meaningful result `0`, without throwing any errors or anything like it:

```
def foo[X](xs: List[X], f: (Int, X) => Int) = {
  xs.foldLeft(0)(f)
}

foo(Nil, (i: Int, n: Nothing) => 42)
```

The presence of `Nothing` in the type system is a Really Good Idea, because it's an initial object (for each other type `A`, there is exactly one function `Nothing => A`), and it simplifies lot of things, because it does not force you to deal with all kind of strange corner cases.

Comment: Agreed on subtyping != inheritance. However, subtyping means a term of type `Bool` can be replaced by a term of type `Nothing`. Why isn't this possible in the expression `!q` ?

Comment: @cuihtlauac in "**term** of **type Bool**" there are two parts: **term** and **type Bool**. You can replace the **term** by `q`, but you still have to specify the **type Bool** somewhere. If your `q` is of type `Nothing`, then the compiler has no possibility to infer that you refer to the method `Bool::unary_!` when you write `!q`. It's the subtyping relation that  determines what you can substitute for what. It's the inheritance relation that determines in which classes the methods are looked up.

Answer (score 0):

> **Nothing** is a subtype of every other type (including scala.Null); there exist no instances of this type

In other words, there are no values of type `Nothing`. So contrary to the statement in your question, you can't pass a `Nothing` typed value to any function (even hypothetically) because it doesn't exist, by definition. Neither can it be a receiver for any method because, again, it doesn't exist.

So the bug, if there is one, is that the compiler does not warn you that you have created a function that can never be called.

---

In this case, `println(q)` works because `Nothing` is a subtype of `Any`, and `q.toString` works because of an implicit conversion of `AnyRef` to `Object` which supports `toString`. The inline function converts `q` to `Boolean` which is also OK, but `Object` does not support `unary_!` so `!q` fails to compile.

Comment: Fine, then why are the first three use of q legal and the fourth not?

Comment: I imagine it is because of the uneasy relationship between Java `Object` and Scala `Any` where the compiler does some fudges to make things work. Specifically, I suspect there is an implicit from `Any` to `Object` so that `toString` works, but `!` doesn't.